# Bibliography - how to fix local language style (change pages to strony)

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, apa-style, polish

I use `papalike` bibliography style that should be a polish counterpart of `apalike` style. 
Unfortunately, within the generated bibliography, word "pages" is used instead of "strony":

[image: pages word is used instead of strony]

According to [Wikipedia](https://pl.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Zarz%C4%85dzanie_bibliografi%C4%85), I added following lines to my document preamble:

```
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\selectbiblanguage{polish}
```

but it results in error only: *Package babelbib Error: Language polish in bibliography unknown by babelbib.*

So that, I would like to ask if it is possible to re-define this one word in bibliography?

My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{mwbk} 

    \usepackage{apalike}
        \let\bibhang\relax
    \usepackage[round]{natbib}
    \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
    \usepackage{floatrow}
        \floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
        \floatsetup[figure]{capposition=bottom}

    \usepackage{polski}
     \usepackage[english, polish]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[unicode, naturalnames, breaklinks]{hyperref}
        \def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}

    \usepackage{longtable,booktabs, graphicx, pdfpages}
        \graphicspath{ {figures/} }

    \raggedbottom

    \usepackage[all]{nowidow}

    \usepackage[lang=english]{bicaption}

    \usepackage[a4paper,includeheadfoot, margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
        \linespread{1.3}

    \usepackage{times}
    \usepackage{mathptmx}
        \urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}

\section{Some text}

\subsection{Some subsection}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vulputate nisi dolor, vitae eleifend sem vehicula a. Nulla libero mi, scelerisque et dapibus at.

\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Einrad}

    \bicaption{Polish caption ĄĆŹŚÓŁ with citation \cite{ScipalTripleCol}}{English caption just below with citation: \cite{ScipalTripleCol}}

    \label{Fig:FIgBicycle}
\end{figure}


\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \bicaption{Polish caption here with special letters: ĄĆŹŚÓŁ}{English caption just below}
    \label{my-label}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
        \hline
        1st col   & 2nd col \\ \hline
        some text & ---     \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

    \bibliographystyle{papalike} %%% THIS should be a polish counterpart of apalike style
    {\footnotesize \bibliography{bibliografia}}

\end{document}
```

My .bib file looks as follows:

```
@article{ScipalTripleCol,
    author={Mark Andrew and Thomas Wo and Jeremy Rex},
    booktitle={There is no such book},
    title = "{Sample Title}",
    year={2010},
    pages={333-1111},
    journal={Journal of LaTeX},
    month={July}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution is to find the `.bst` style file and grep it for pages. You should have something like this inside:

```
FUNCTION {bbl.pages}
{ "strony" }

FUNCTION {bbl.page}
{ "strona" }
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please do not advocate changing files of the TeX distribution directly. If you want to modify a file, copy it, rename it and make modifications only of the copied version. Ideally you'd add a comment to the changed file what you did and when you did it.

Comment: Note that `apalike.bst` does not have `bbl.pages` and `bbl.page` macros, it has `FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages empty$
    { "" }
    { pages multi.page.check
        { "pages" pages n.dashify tie.or.space.connect }
        { "page" pages tie.or.space.connect }
      if$
    }
  if$
}` that should be changed.

Comment: Is it possible to modify this in my .tex file (maybe after selecting style, redefining this macro?). I would like to avoid direct .bst file amendments.

Comment: @marcin-kawka Please include also information where this file could be found. in different TeX.SX I found information that command `kpsewhich papalike.bst` provides an answer `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/przechlewski-book/papalike.bst`

Comment: @marcin-kawka Please also include @moewe suggestion, so that I can mark your response as an answer - there is no bbl.pages macro, i modified papalike.bst as follows: `FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages empty$
    { "" }
    { pages multi.page.check
 { "strony" pages n.dashify tie.or.space.connect }
 { "strona" pages tie.or.space.connect }
      if$
    }
  if$
}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it would work with apastyle, but you can copy `polish.lbx` from `/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx` (in case of arch linux at least) next to your tex file and then edit it inplace. For example change line:

```
page             = {{strona}{s\adddot}},
```